# Confluence: Force browsers to load the Javascript(jquery) changes with out manual hard refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, confluence

I am using Jquery(in theme configuration) as explained [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/how-to-use-javascript-in-confluence-313458839.html) to Hide/Show some elements in the Confluence Wiki Pages.

The changes in this java-script is not reflected unless I do a hard refresh on the browser.

As it is not possible to make all the users to do manual hard refresh on their browsers, is there a way in confluence to force the browser to update the local javascript?

Comment: Give the file a new filename.

Comment: Just append a timestamp to the js filename so the browser won't cache the file, assuming this is what is causing the user to do a manual hard refresh of their browser.  `filename.js?nocache=currenttimestamp`  then you can just refresh the page with `location.reload()`

Comment: Off topic: be careful with jQuery, as Atlassian uses his own jQuery wrapper "AJS".